# Reverse Proxy on Apache/Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, apache2.4

i need to setup reverse proxy with Lets Encrypt for multiple app servers. I installed
**Webagte server:**

```
Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS
Apache 2.4
```

Apache runs OK and "first" page show.
But when i put this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin "my@mail.tld"
ServerName "app1.mydomain.tld"
DocumentRoot "/var/www/app1.mydomain.tld"
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/.well-known/" !
ProxyPass "/test-broker/" !
ProxyPass "/" "http://192.168.1.21:20000/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.1.21:20000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

to file /etc/apache2/sitest-enabled/000-default.conf and open my browser page i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

**Checklist:**

- /var/www/app1.mydomain.tld exist.
- http://192.168.1.21:20000/ work.
- app1.mydomain.tld in DNS exist and is pointed to webgate server.
- a2enmod proxy enabled.
- a2enmod proxy_http enabled.
- a2enmod proxy_ajp enabled.
- a2enmod rewrite enabled.
- a2enmod deflate enabled.
- a2enmod headers enabled.
- a2enmod proxy_balancer enabled.
- a2enmod proxy_connect enabled.
- a2enmod proxy_html enabled.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could be a client problem. Can you try it from another browser and or another machine? Can you reach it with `curl` over command line? https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Answer (score 0):

The virtual host you have there will only get used on HTTP traffic, so the server is refusing a connection from browser on standard HTTPS port 443.

You will need an additional virtual host for 443 `<VirtualHost *:443>` which has ssl config included as per [Apache SSL HowTo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).